# Changing css styling dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-manipulation

I'm practicing javascript. Here I'm creating a JS class for dynamically creating web elements such as `div`, `a`, etc. The following code shows a class for creating a `div` element:

```js
class DivBlock {

 //creates the div element
 constructor(id) {
   this.ele = document.createElement('div');
   this.ele.id = id;
   this.ele.style.height = '100px';
   this.ele.style.width = '200px';
   this.ele.style.border = '1px solid black';
 }

 // sets the css properties
 css(props) {
   var keyslist = Object.keys(props);
   console.log(keyslist);
   console.log(props);
   var style = keyslist.map((keys) => {
     this.ele.style.keys = props[keys];
     return this.ele.style.keys;
   });
   console.log(style);
 }

 getId() {
   return this.ele.id;
 }

 getNode() {
   return this.ele;
 }

 //adds the div-element to the parent element/tag
 mount(parent_id) {
   document.getElementById(parent_id).appendChild(this.ele);
 }

}

var d = new DivBlock('root-div');
d.mount('root') //passing parent tag id
d.css({
 height: '500px',
 backgroundColor: 'red'
});
```

The Html snippet:

```html
<div id='root'> </div>
```

The above code is successfully creating the `div` but is not changing the height and background-color as mentioned by the `css` method. The `css` method should take an object having css-styling properties and its values and reflect the changes. What changes should I make in the `css` method or in the code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `this.ele.style.keys = props[keys];` to `this.ele.style[keys] = props[keys];`

`keys` is  variable so you need to use the bracket notation to access the prop with name that is in the variable. Otherwise you are trying to access a property of the `style` named literally `keys`.

---

```js
class DivBlock {

  //creates the div element
  constructor(id) {
    this.ele = document.createElement('div');
    this.ele.id = id;
    this.ele.style.height = '100px';
    this.ele.style.width = '200px';
    this.ele.style.border = '1px solid black';
  }

  // sets the css properties
  css(props) {
    var keyslist = Object.keys(props);
    console.log(keyslist);
    console.log(props);
    var style = keyslist.map((keys) => {
      this.ele.style[keys] = props[keys];
      return this.ele.style[keys];
    });
    console.log(style);
  }

  getId() {
    return this.ele.id;
  }

  getNode() {
    return this.ele;
  }

  //adds the div-element to the parent element/tag
  mount(parent_id) {
    document.getElementById(parent_id).appendChild(this.ele);
  }

}

var d = new DivBlock('root-div');
d.mount('root') //passing parent tag id
d.css({
  height: '500px',
  backgroundColor: 'red'
});
```

```html
<div id='root'> </div>
```